# Trying to host .NET core 2.1 web app in window service creates dll instead of exe

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Following the instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/windows-service?view=aspnetcore-2.0&tabs=aspnetcore2x) I:

- installed visual studio 2017 preview
- installed .NET Core 2.1 RC1
- `dotnet add package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WindowsServices --version 2.1.0-rc1-final`

new project ->  
select .NET Core on the left -> 
select ASP.NET Core Web Application -> 
select ASP.NET Core 2.1 on the top -> 
select Web Application -> 
in program.cs add `using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WindowsServices;` -> 
in program.cs change `Run()` to `RunAsService()` -> 
build release -> 
in cmd do `dotnet publish`

I get:

```
>dotnet publish
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.7.177.53362 for .NET Core
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

  Restoring packages for C:\Temp\VoyDashServer\VoyDashServer\VoyDashServer\VoyDashServer.csproj...
  Generating MSBuild file C:\Temp\VoyDashServer\VoyDashServer\VoyDashServer\obj\VoyDashServer.csproj.nuget.g.props.
  Restore completed in 1.56 sec for C:\Temp\VoyDashServer\VoyDashServer\VoyDashServer\VoyDashServer.csproj.
  You are working with a preview version of the .NET Core SDK. You can define the SDK version via a global.json file in the current project. More at https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=869452
  VoyDashServer -> C:\Temp\VoyDashServer\VoyDashServer\VoyDashServer\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\VoyDashServer.dll
  VoyDashServer -> C:\Temp\VoyDashServer\VoyDashServer\VoyDashServer\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\VoyDashServer.Views.dll
  VoyDashServer -> C:\Temp\VoyDashServer\VoyDashServer\VoyDashServer\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\publish\
```

That is the result is a dll and not an exe

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Camilo, I followed the instructions here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/windows-service?view=aspnetcore-2.0&tabs=aspnetcore2x which are supposed to produce an exe even through it's a .net core web app

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the last step, instead of `dotnet publish` do

```
dotnet publish -c Release --self-contained -r win-x64
```

That will generate the .exe

Comment: I still get a dll :(

Comment: you will get a dll and an exe?

Comment: i guess one thing to be mindful of -> this command has to be run against .csproj, not .sln; also, it generates two folders -> `/bin/Release/win-x64/` and `/bin/Release/win-x64/publish`. The exe is only in the second one